# How to properly test angular service stream

Tags: angular, jasmine, jasmine-marbles

I'm trying to test a service data stream that looks something like this:

```
loadHeader() {
    this.cbData.fetchHeader()
        .pipe(
            tap(header => console.log('FIRST: ', header)),
            withLatestFrom(this.user.userInfo$),
            map(([header, user]) => {
                console.log(header);
                console.log(user);
                if (user) {
                    header.userProfile.user = user;
                }

                return header;
            }),
            tap(header => this.cbHeader.saveHeaderData(header)),
            tap(header => console.log('Im def here: ', header)),
        )
        .subscribe();
}
```

using a test case along these lines:

```
fit('adds user info when user supplied', fakeAsync(() => {
    const u: UserAuthInfo = <UserAuthInfo>{ id: '1' };
    const h = { userProfile: {} };

    const header$ = cold('-x--|', { x: h });
    const user$ = cold('--y-|', { y: u });

    spyOn(cbData, 'fetchHeader').and.returnValue(header$);
    user.userInfo$ = <any>user$;

    spyOn(cbHeader, 'saveHeaderData').and.callThrough();

    service.loadHeader();
    tick(40);

    expect(cbHeader.saveHeaderData).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ userProfile: { user: { id: '1' } } });
}));
```

This doesn't work.  I've tried a number of other variations on the test code (like sending info through userInfo$(it's a BehaviorSubject) directly with next()) - but mostly, I'm hoping can give me more general suggestion for this type of scenario.

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work" - are you getting an error?  If so please post details. Is there a reason for using marble testing?  You may want to try a simple mock with `of()` to return a synchronous cold observable to simplify things a bit.

Comment: @dmcgrandle yes, sorry, it's never triggering the spy on cbHeader (weirdly, i AM seeing the logs from within the service surrounding the cbHeader object.  And yes, I can switch to of() or call getTestScheduler().flush() and get it to work - BUT, I'd rather be able to step through time frames using ticket to verify when updates occur.

Comment: You are probably spying on the wrong service (ie not the one instantiated in your component).  Include all the initial code in your .spec file including the surrounding describe(s) for this spec.